# Replacing all occurance of characters using StringBuffer class

Tags: java

I want to use **StringBuffer class** instead of **String class** but i dont find any method to replace all occurance of characters by **StringBuffer class** like that of **String class** through *replace()* method.

Code below:

```
class Ram{  
public static void main(String args[]){  
StringBuffer sb=new StringBuffer("Hello my dear ,Hello,Hello,Hello");  
sb.replace(1,3,"Java");  
System.out.println(sb);//prints HJavalo  
}  
}
```

Output:
    HJavalo my dear ,Hello,Hello,Hello

I m new to java programming and i want to know if any method or technique is there to replace all those *Hello* with *java* .Thanks

Comment: Why do you want to use `StringBuffer` instead of `String`?

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, if you want to use a mutable `String` object for better performing concatenations etc. you probably want a `StringBuilder`, not a `StringBuffer` (that is unless your code manipulating it is multi-threaded, but I doubt it, given the example).

Secondly, in this case you're much better off using `String#replace` or `String#replaceAll`, which is actually invoked by `String#replace`.

Here's what the optimized code would look like:

```
StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder(
    "Hello my dear ,Hello,Hello,Hello"
    .replace("Hello", "Java")
);
System.out.println(sb);
```

**Output**

```
Java my dear ,Java,Java,Java
```